# Can I award a bounty to the asker who asked it?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, down-votes, up-votes

I sometimes feel the need to reward the asker for posting a very useful and thoughtful question. Bounties are rewarded for answers, and not for questions. I can only upvote the question once, but if I'm ready to spare rep, is there any way I can reward the asker?

Comment: By placing the bounty you are drawing more attention to the question, which usually means more upvotes. This is a reward by itself to the question author.

Answer (score 1):

At present working of bounty, no there is not.

The bounty can be awarded only to answer.

To award the bounty to the OP, ask him to make an answer and then award it for the answer. Anyway I am not supporting this because, only to get bounty, if the OP answered his own question in which there is already an answer exists, if it is a plagiarism, it may subject to mod's actions.

Comment: Wait, we can only award bounties to accepted answers right?

Comment: no. The person who award the bounty can select the answer. If no answer selected, if there exists an answer with score 2+ which is posted in the bounty period, the half of the bounty will be awarded to it automatically. If there are more answers matching this criteria, the old one will be chosen. If the answer is also the accepted one, then full bounty will be awarded. @PrittBalagopal Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty